# Is converting timestamp to datetime in django will convert datetime by default to datetime in UTC

Tags: django, datetime

I am creating an app which will use peoples from different timezones. I have a model

```
class Fixture(models.Model):                        
   fixture_id =models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)                                        
   event_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I want while creating objects from this model that event_date field save datetime object in UTC to convert it in user's timezone while show him this data in front-end. 
In django documentation i read that

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

Now i am creating an object

```
b = Fixture.objects.create(fixture_id = fixture, event_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(variable_contained_timestamp))
```

Is according django documentation in event_date field will be stored datetime object in UTC  not in datetime object with my database time zone

Comment: Apologies, what's the question?

Comment: @2ps it is question no additional questions ;)